# How to add custom animatable property to UIImageView's subclass?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, properties

I have the class that I subclassed from UIImageView. The instance of this class is then added as a subview to the my application's root class. Now, I can animate it's properties, for example, setFrame:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
...
[myImageView setFrame:someFrameCreatedInCode];
...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This takes the current frame as the initial state and interpolates imageview animation (it simply moves from the left to the right). **This part works fine.**

What I would like to do next is I want to add a property to my class, say, of integer type. And I want this property to cpecify the image number (it's name is formatted) and make frame based animation later. It seems to be a nice way to create animation because I can specify the "curve" to affect the animation timing:

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

How to implement my own property which is possible to animate?

Thanks in advance!

Update: In case someone will need this I found these tutorials in the Internet: [blog post](http://www.nomadplanet.fr/2010/11/animate-calayer-custom-properties-with-coreanimation/), [sample](https://gist.github.com/868878).

Comment: What do you mean by "image number"?

Comment: "Number" is a number in the filename. Actually I suppose it doesn't matter at the moment. I think I will use the file naming or array index to swap the frames during animation.

Comment: Are you using UIImageView's animationImages property?

Comment: I used startAnimating/stopAnimating earlier but now I found this unconvinient because it lacks the control capabilities. There are only a couple of methods available to start, stop and check the status of animation running. But if I could use for example the CALayer capabilities approach It would be possible to get more control over my animation. I did some internet search and think that it's possible to add animatable properties to CALayer's subclass. I'm still working on this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use the UIView animations together with the UIImageView animation images.

If you use a code like this:

```
colors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select4.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select5.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select6.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select7.png"],    
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_select8.png"],nil];

animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

animationView.animationImages = colors;
animationView.animationDuration = 1.0;
animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // loop

[animationView startAnimating];
```

I think the only problem would be synchronizing the two animations ...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer first of all. Yes, there is such a problem. As I mentioned in my previous comments this type of animation doesn't have to much control properties or methods to affect the running animation. And I found almost the same solution but instead of using UIImageView's built in animation I used the NSTimer executing "swap function" to play the animation. But in this case all the timing and synchronization procedures I had to implement from scratch. What I would like to do now is to use CALayer's (UIView's) custom animatable properties to create an animation.